# Cannot open database "ABC" requested by the login. The log in failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I am using the following code to connect to SQL with VBA and getting the error at the title

```
 ' Create a connection object.
    Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
    Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

    ' Provide the connection string.
    Dim dbms As String
    Dim strConn As String

   ' Specify the OLE DB provider.
    cnPubs.Provider = "SQLNCLI"

    'Set SQLOLEDB connection properties.
    cnPubs.Properties("Data Source").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("B3")
    cnPubs.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("B4")

    ' Windows NT authentication.
    cnPubs.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"

    'Now open the connection.
    cnPubs.Open
```

I didn't have issues before while I was using SQL authentication as I could specify username and password. Now I need to use Windows authentication and I am getting an error.

I think the issue is with the autofill of username when I select Windows authentication
at SQL login. Cross referenced with SQL login page
Server type: Database engine
Servername: Server\Database
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Locked selection:
Username: NT.COMPANY.COM\username
password:

anyone know how I can log in to Server\Database?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting can be caused by one of two things:

1. The database you are trying to open does not exist
2. The account you are using has not bee granted access to the database

Because you are saying that connecting to the database works with SQL Authentication, you are most likely running into 2. To fix this you need to grant access to that database to your windows login.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I can access with Windows Authentication on my computer but I am getting the error when I try through VBA. Is there a specific way to gain access while using VBA?

Comment: Can you post the values that you use to set the properties of cnPubs? Can you also post the exact error you are geting?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help I figured out the problem. The issue was not the connection but rather the wrong database name that I was given.